# Схлопывание кода в Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublime-text

Мощный редактор. Устраивает почти всё. Не хватает только нормального схлопывания кода. Как решить эту проблему? Например, не сворачиваются блоки PHP-кода, JavaScript некорректно схлопывается. Буду рад помощи - раздражает запредельно.

Comment: А вас не устроит WebStorm 4.0? Мне кажется что это самая лучшая IDE для JavaScript/PHP/CSS/HTML/ASP net и там по синтаксису схлопывание..

Comment: @Rules - платная же. Sublime Text условно платный (надоедающий диалог =))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я не ошибаюсь, встроенное сворачивание кода в sublime работает не по синтаксису, а по индентации. Соблюдайте отступы, и все у вас свернется =)

Ну и два очевидных выхода, если не устраивает такое сворачивание:

1. Найти плагин (я глянул в package control по слову fold, не нашел. Можно еще поискать на форумах [здесь](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewforum.php?f=5&sid=bc274bc22d355229346f5e15528cc688) и [здесь](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewforum.php?f=6&sid=bc274bc22d355229346f5e15528cc688))
2. Написать свой плагин

Answer (score 0):

Полагаю, некоторых пользователей могут не устроить ответы «не нашёл плагин», «можно поискать на форумах» и «написать свой плагин», поэтому позволю себе дополнить [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/109649/199934).

Ув-мым gridsane верно отмечено, что встроенное сворачивание в Sublime Text работает по индентации, а не синтаксису. Соответственно, нам нужно автоматически настроить отступы formatter'ом (beautifier'ом):

Какой форматтер для JavaScript использую я и почему, см. [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/513835/199934).

Демонстрация сворачивания после форматирования посредством [js-beautify](https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify)
.

[image: Cхлопывание JavaScript в Sublime Text 3]

я не знаю языка PHP, посему не могу порекомендовать beautifier, основываясь на личном опыте. Упомяну только, что на англоязычном Stack Overflow [советуют](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18419157/which-is-the-best-php-beautifier-extension-for-sublime-text) плагины [CodeIntel](https://github.com/SublimeCodeIntel/SublimeCodeIntel) и [CodeFormatter](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/CodeFormatter).

Спасибо.