# Разворачивание javascript, записанного одной строкой (в частности, в Sublime Text 3)

Tags: javascript, sublime-text, sublime-text-3

Есть `.js` файл , в котором код написан в 1 строку (compressed), а вот нужно мне его посмотреть, поправить. В общем, как его обратно перевести в expanded стиль?

В SASS можно подставить код, выбрать стиль — и всё получится, а как поступать с JavaScript?

Comment: http://jsbeautifier.org/ — лучший из опробованных мной онлайн-форматтеров. Каким текстовым редактором пользуетесь? Если Sublime Text, распишу решение для него. Спасибо.

Comment: Да sublime пользуюсь, но как то еще не понял как через него

Comment: Сейчас тогда напишу ответ.

Comment: Я на том сервисе уже отформатировал, но  вссе равно жду

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ПО, в частности, разворачивающее код, записанный в одну строчку, а вообще делающее его удобным для восприятия человеком, называется `formatter` или `beautifier`.

#### Общее решение для js

[Online JavaScript beautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/). В сети можно отыскать и альтернативы, но лично меня и этот сервис полностью устраивает. Внизу по ссылке указан список `formatter`'ов для браузеров, текстовых редакторов, IDE и т. д. — выбирайте в зависимости от того, чем Вы пользуетесь.

#### Решение для Sublime Text 3

На Stack Overflow [рекомендуют](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21206739/5951529) плагин [HTMLPrettify](https://github.com/victorporof/Sublime-HTMLPrettify), (требуется предустановка платформы [`Node.js`](https://nodejs.org/en/) ), при использовании которого у меня не возникало проблем с `.html` и `.css`; а вот некоторые `.js`, а именно файлы шрифтов, внедрённых через [Cufón](http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/), плагин отказывался правильно форматировать. Не разворачивает js и встроенное в Sublime Text 3 средство: выделяем текст, нажав <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>, → <kbd>Edit</kbd> → <kbd>Line</kbd> → <kbd>Reindent</kbd>.

Подошёл плагин [js-beautify](https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify). После его установки в файле, который необходимо отформатировать, следует нажать куда-нибудь правой кнопкой мыши и в выпадающем меню выбрать <kbd>JavascriptBeautify</kbd>. Код развернётся и обретёт красивый вид.

До:

[image: js-код до обработки js-beautify]

После:

[image: js-код после обработки js-beautify]

Спасибо.