# Как пакетно конвертировать пробелы в отступы в Sublime Text 3

Tags: регулярные-выражения, sublime-text-3

Как без ущерба проекту пакетно заменить пробелы на табы? Я имею ввиду, чтобы не открывать каждый файл, если файлов больше тысячи, — замучаться можно, — а сделать это массово.

**UPD.** Саша, спасибо большое за ссылки, думаю, одна из них приблизила меня к цели. :) Только когда я вписываю в поиск `Find: {4}`, ST3 пишет, что ничего не найдено. К сожалению, Windows у меня действительно нет под рукой. Ещё не совсем понимаю смысл вот этой фразы:

> As mentioned in comments to match spaces at the start of a line you
>   can use the regexp ^( {4})+

**UPD. 2** Большое Вам спасибо! Действительно, всё получилось, вот только проблема в том, что ST3 открыл все файлы, и каждый приходится сохранять. Можно ли как-то сделать, чтобы он сам всё сохранил и закрыл? Или, может, существует другое, альтернативное решение?

Comment: Предположу, что Вам beautifier нужен, который все табы правильно расставит. Какой язык программирования? Пример для JavaScript см. [**здесь**](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/513835/199934). Спасибо.

Comment: Если интересует только поставленная задача, то [**2 варианта**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22529265/5951529).

Comment: *Отредактировал свой ответ согласно вашей правке*

Comment: Снежана, [**так**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20675429/5951529) пробовали?

Comment: Снежана, `Ctrl + Shift + F` → в поле напротив `Find` введите `^( {4})+` → в поле напротив `Replace` — `\t`. [**Вот так**](https://i.gyazo.com/a357b6d0106fc85530cbc27ec2b8258f.png). Должны быть включены регулярные выражения — самая левая кнопка. Далее нажмите на кнопку с тремя точками в правом нижнем углу → `Add Folder` → выбираете свой проект → `Replace`. Сразу менять пробелы на табы в тысячах файлов не рекомендую: Sublime Text 3 может зависнуть. Попробуйте сначала на нескольких. В моём проекте на 138 файлов [**всё нашлось**](https://i.gyazo.com/7bf0f38ca9e0bd12d3b841128f343d79.png). Спасибо.

Comment: Снежана, `File` → `Save All`. Если ещё возникнут вопросы, пожалуйста, оставляйте их в комментариях, а не путём апдейтов в самом вопросе: `Добавить комментарий` → напишите `@Саша Черных` → текст Вашего вопроса. Так я смогу получать уведомления от Вас (подписаться не на свой вопрос на этом сайте нельзя).

Comment: Снежана, если всё получилось, отметьте, пожалуйста, ответ галочкой.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4):

В основном меню: `View` - `Indentaion`

[image: отступы]

На оффсайте можно почитать подробности: [Indentation Settings](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/indentation)

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>Ctrl + Shift + F</kbd>:

Напротив <kbd>Find:</kbd> вставляем регулярное выражение `^ {4}`, где 4 — количество пробелов, которые мы заменяем отступом. По умолчанию — 4, если прежде не меняли никаких настроек индентации, оставляйте `^ {4}`. Регулярные выражения должны быть включены самой левой кнопкой консоли «Find in files» (той, которую мы вызвали шорткатом <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + F</kbd>).

Напротив <kbd>Where:</kbd> нажимаем на кнопку <kbd>...</kbd> → <kbd>Add Folder</kbd> → выбираем папку проекта. Если проект очень большой на тысячи файлов, рекомендовал бы производить замену по частям, ибо при работе с огромными массивами Sublime Text 3 имеет свойство подвисать.

Напротив <kbd>Replace:</kbd> вставляем `\t` — метасимвол табуляции.

Получается так:

[image: Консоль «Find in files»]

Жмём на <kbd>Replace</kbd> → файлы, в которых произведена замена, откроются в новых вкладках, → в верхнем меню кликаем <kbd>File</kbd> → <kbd>Save All</kbd>. Замена произведена. <kbd>File</kbd> → <kbd>Close All Files</kbd> — все вкладки закроются.

Для тех, кто пакетно работает с множеством файлов, не покажется лишним плагин [TabExtra](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/TabsExtra), добавляющий новые возможности при работе с вкладками. Положим, в нашем примере мы сделали массовую замену, но где-то опечатались в синтаксисе регулярных выражений, из-за чего получилось не то, что требовалось. Кликаем правой кнопкой мыши по любой вкладке → <kbd>Close Tab(s): Dismiss Unsaved</kbd> → <kbd>Close All Tabs</kbd> → все вкладки закроются без сохранения.

[image: Tab Extra close without saving]

На английском Stack Overflow [рекомендуют](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20675429/5951529) использовать шаблон `^( {4})+`. Однако если Ваш код отформатирован каким-нибудь [Beautifier'ом](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21206739/5951529), то оформление может испортиться, и придётся форматировать заново.

*Пример применения моего регулярного выражения:*
[image: Моё регулярное выражение]

*Пример применения регулярного выражения, рекомендованного на англоязычном Stack Overflow:*
[image: Регулярное выражение, рекомендованное на английском SO]

Разберём модель `^( {4})+`:

`^` — метасимвол начала строки. Если его не использовать, в отступы отконвертируются пробелы, стоящие не только в начале строки, но и в любом другом месте текста.
`( {4})` — пробел, повторённый 4 раза. Эквивалентно `(    )`.
`+` — квантор, означающий повторение выражения в скобках 1 или более раз. Другими словами 4, 8, 12 и другие кратные четырём количества пробелов подряд заменятся на один отступ. Код может выстроиться в один столбец как на примере.

Если не желаете терять оформление, используйте регулярное выражение `^ {4}`.

---

Чтобы проблемы с табами/пробелами в дальнейшем не беспокоили, в какой бы операционной системе и IDE/редакторе ни работали разработчики проекта, сейчас [повсеместно](https://github.com/editorconfig/editorconfig/wiki/Projects-Using-EditorConfig) для [каждого мало-мальски используемого редактора или IDE](http://editorconfig.org/) применяется плагин EditorConfig. После установки через PackageControl в папке проекта создаём файл `.editorconfig`, куда вставляем следующий текст:

```
# editorconfig.org
root = true

[*]
indent_style = tab
indent_size = 4
end_of_line = lf
charset = utf-8
trim_trailing_whitespace = true
insert_final_newline = true

[*.md]
trim_trailing_whitespace = false
```

У всех файлов проекта будет автоматически настраиваться `Tab_Size:4`, пусть вы поставили или редактор определил («умное» автоопределение можно отключить в открывающийся после <kbd>Preferences</kbd> → <kbd>Settings - User</kbd> файл, добавив в него строку `"detect indentation": false`, однако Sublime Text 3 всё равно порой устанавливает индентацию по-своему) иначе.

Представлены значения по умолчанию, можете менять их по своему усмотрению, подробности [в статье на Хабрахабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/220131/). [Поддерживаемые настройки для Sublime Text](https://github.com/sindresorhus/editorconfig-sublime#supported-properties).

Answer (score 4):

В unix-подобных системах существует утилита `unexpand`.
Для обработки группы файлов можно написать простенький скрипт на `bash`:

```
find . -name '*.[ch]' -exec sh -c 'unexpand {} > tmp.~ && mv tmp.~ {}' \;
```

`expand` делает обратную замену.