# Как с SublimeText3 привести код в папке src к одному виду?

Tags: sublime-text

Как привести всё к следующим правилам -
indent_style = space,
indent_size = 4,
весь проект автоматически, который находится в папке src?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно регулярным выражением найти все табы и поменять на 4 пробела

1. Ctrl+Shift+F
2. Убедиться что включен поиск по рег выражению
3. Find: \t , Replace: (4 пробела)
4. в поле "where" можно указать в какой папке осуществлять замену

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а можно как-нибудь допустим найти где вместо 4 пробелов 2?

Comment: @drtvader также поиск по рег выражению. в поле find - ^\s\s , в поле replace 4 пробела

Comment: @drtvader также есть плагины - бьютифайеры для сублайма, с помощью которых можно автоматически выровнять код. Напрмиер https://packagecontrol.io/packages/HTML-CSS-JS%20Prettify для хтмл цсс и яваскрипт, хорошо настраивается

Comment: Спасибо! Установлю себе!

Comment: Almaz V., **1)** Лучше использовать `^ {4}`, а не 4 пробела. **2)** После конвертации, чтобы проблема больше не беспокоила, следует применить плагин EditorConfig.

Причины я подробно расписал в [**этом**](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/517809/199934) ответе. Спасибо.