# Как заменить все повторяющиеся фрагменты кода в macOS?

Tags: netbeans, sublime-text, sublime-text-3, brackets

Есть фрагмент кода типа:

```
return array(
    'meta' => array(
        'code' => 200,
    ),
);
```

Но их много, и я хочу заменить их таким кодом:

```
return metaSuccess();
```

У Notepad++ всё очень легко: выбираю код, нажимаю <kbd>Ctrl+F</kbd> и потом заменяю всё.

Но в Mac не могу делать того же с программами Sublime Text, Brackets, NetBeans. А Notepad++ нету для macOS.

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста. // **1.** Вам необходимо провести замену в проекте, папке или просто одном файле? // **2.** Вам требуется осуществить прямую замену — один одинаковый текст везде заменить на другой одинаковый текст везде, — или есть какие-то нюансы? Спасибо.

Comment: Установите себе на виртуалку Windows

Comment: 1.   В одном файле.

Comment: 2. Прямую замену. Просто у меня  там код не однострочная.

Comment: Fəqan Çələbizadə, **1.** Чтобы участнику, которому Вы ответили, приходили уведомления о Вашем ответе, пожалуйста, используйте конструкцию `@$Имя_участника$`, например, `@СашаЧерных`. // 2. Ответил для Sublime Text, но это просто выходит. Возможно, у Вас более серьёзная проблема, тогда детальнее опишите её. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Выбрать папку, в которой желаете провести замену, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> и заменяйте текст на нужный.

Comment: Неплохо хотя бы сказать, в каком редакторе/IDE помогут описанные Вами действия. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

### 1. Поиск и замена в Sublime Text

Выделение и замена всех совпадений— относительно несложная для реализации и нужная функция. Уверен, что она есть в любом продвинутом текстовом редакторе и IDE.

В Sublime Text можно производить поиск и замену при помощи регулярных выражений, — используется библиотека [**Oniguruma**](https://github.com/kkos/oniguruma), — или, к примеру, [**инкрементальные**](https://github.com/born2c0de/Incrementor), [**множественные одной командой**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/586841/199934) поиск и замену. В зависимости от используемого компьютерного языка могут найтись пакеты под определённые запросы. Но простого выделения всех вхождений с последующей заменой достаточно возможностей «из коробки».

---

### 2. Демонстрация

[image: Поиск и замена в Sublime Text]

---

### 3. ***find_all_under***

Когда мне нужно произвести замену в одном файле, самое удобное решение — команда `find_all_under`. Дефолтное сочетание для macOS — <kbd>Ctrl+Super+G</kbd>, для Windows — <kbd>Alt+F3</kbd>. Выделяете повторяющийся кусок кода → запускаете команду `find_all_under` → вставляете или вводите код, на который нужно производить замену: замена будет произведена во всех местах.

К сожалению, многие разработчики пакетов для Sublime Text имеют нехорошую особенность перезаписывать сочетания клавиш, предназначенные для команд «из коробки», если у Вас не работают сочетания выше, добавьте в свой `Default.suricate-profile` файл следующие строки:

```json
"select_all_highlighted": {
    "caption": "Select All Highlighted",
    "keys": ["shift+super+f3"],
    "call": "sublime.find_all_under"
},
```

Где

- `Select All Highlighted` — имя, которое будет отображаться для команды `find_all_under` в command palette;
- `shift+super+f3` — Ваше не занятое глобально или в Sublime Text сочетание клавиш.

Что такое Suricate, и как им пользоваться, я подробно описал [**здесь**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/586841/199934) и [**здесь**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/587973/199934).

---

### 4. Find in files

Для поставленной в вопросе задачи можно воспользоваться и встроенным механизмом поиска и замены, что, на мой взгляд, менее удобно. Но когда требуется произвести замену во множестве файлов, можно [**воспользоваться панелью Find in files**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/517809/199934). Выделяете повторяющийся фрагмент кода → запускаете команду `show_panel` с аргументом `{"panel": "find_in_files"}` — <kbd>Cmd/Ctrl+Shift+F</kbd> → вставляете повторяющийся фрагмент кода — <kbd>Cmd/Ctrl+V</kbd> → <kbd>Tab</kbd> → <kbd>Tab</kbd> → вставляете код, на который нужно заменить → жмёте на кнопку `Replace` → `Replace` → если результат удовлетворяет, [**сохраняете и закрываете все вкладки**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/517809/199934).

В панелях Find and replace или Find in files можно и вводить многострочный код, а не только вставлять: помещаем курсор в поле напротив `Find What:` или `Replace With:` в Find and replace/`Find:` или `Replace:` в Find in files → напечатали первую строку → <kbd>Ctrl+Enter</kbd> → печатаем вторую строку → <kbd>Ctrl+Enter</kbd> → печатаем третью и т. д. Но считаю, что это менее удобный способ в сравнении со вставкой.

---

### 5. Дополнительная ссылка

- [**О различных видах выделения текста в Sublime Text**](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/editing/editing.html).