# Существует ли плагин для автоматического изменения css?

Tags: css, ide, sublime-text

Встала задача добавить всем классам в css префикс r-. 
Есть ли плагины для текстовых редакторов чтобы можно было автоматически менять нужный css?

Comment: А если регулярными выражениями сделать? Есть у Вас какие-либо аргументы против? Для HTML (не знаю, какими препроцессорами пользуетесь) оно будет примерно [**таким**](https://regex101.com/r/9QMxiN/1), для CSS — [**таким**](https://regex101.com/r/qdAZH3/1). Как осуществлять поиск и замену во множестве файлов в Sublime Text см. [**здесь**](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/search_and_replace/search_and_replace_files.html) и [**здесь**](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/517809/199934). Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных Спасибо за ответ!