# Как заменить 4 пробела на 2 в Sublime

Tags: sublime-text, редактор, tabs

Основываясь на этом [вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/517694/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8B-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%8B-%D0%B2-sublime-text-3/745564?noredirect=1) стало понятно как конвертировать 4 пробела в табы, но как конвертировать 4 пробела в 2?

Comment: вы где хотите их заменить, в начале строк, или в принципе по всему тексту?

Comment: по всему тексту, например есть код с нестингом и везде 4 пробела, нужно 2

Comment: если выбрать файл заменить идентацию с пробелов на табы потом выбрать с 4х на 2, то весь текст отформатируется автоматически, но нужно этот процесс сделать не в ручную.

Comment: весь текст это весь текст, включая например, пробелы внутри каких нибудь строковых литералов. А отступы в начале строк, это именно отступы, вот про них я так понимаю и речь тогда идет?

Comment: да, речь об отступах.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Visual Code Studio работает такой метод:

Регулярка для поиска: `^( {2,})(\1)`
Строка подмены: `$2`

P.S. Правда 6 пробелов превратятся в 3 ;)
P.P.S. Улучшенный вариант для поиска: `^((?:  )+)(\1)`

Comment: @stackflow, а я о чем написал в ответе? Если автору не подойдет регулярка из-за другой реализации работы регулярок поиска в Sublime Text, то ответ ни когда не поздно удалить. Или вы мне предлагаете его установить и проверить?