# Сервис для правки кода

Tags: javascript, синтаксис

Подскажите пожалуйста ресурсы, на котором можно минифицированный код преобразовать в [стандартный стиль кода](https://learn.javascript.ru/coding-style).

Пример:

1.

```
var a = 1;function b(){return 1;}
```

2.

```
var a = 1;

function b() {
  return 1;
}
```

Comment: https://www.google.ru/search?q=javascript+unminify

Comment: @maxwell так банально. в голову не приходило как загуглить) напиши как ответ. спасибо

Comment: [**Здесь**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/513835/199934) отвечал на аналогичный вопрос для Sublime Text. Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных спасибо тебе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.** Запрос в Google с названиями: Javascript Unminify, Beautifier, Formatter.

**2.** Был схожий [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/513819/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-javascript-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B2-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B2-sublime-tex/513835#513835) по этой теме.

В ответе участвовали пользователи: [maxwell](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/222188/maxwell), [Саша Черных](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/199934/%D0%A1%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B0-%D0%A7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85).